# he made his clothes wash/washed

Tags: sentence-construction

Is either of these sentences correct?

> He made his clothes **washed**

or

> He made his clothes **wash**

Comment: Neither one sounds idiomatic. You should say: _**He washed his clothes**_.

Comment: @J.R. I agree but what about he was forcing someone to wash his clothes? Can we say "He made her wash his clothes" or "He made his clothes to be washed"?

Comment: @RubioRic: we might say *"he had his clothes washed"* or *"he had her wash his clothes"* if he got somebody else to do it. You'd only say *"he made her wash his clothes"* if she didn't want to wash them.

Comment: Here, _he_ and _his_ refer to two different persons

Comment: If _he_ and _his_ refer to two different persons, the you’ve picked a bad place to use pronouns. Either way, the sentence is still poorly constructed: ***Bob made Joe’s clothes wash/washed*** still sounds like nonsense. It’s ***Bob washed Joe’s clothes***.

Comment: Then....Is the sentence'he made your clothes washed' right.?

Comment: No, it’s “He washed your clothes.” The phrase “made your clothes washed” is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic would be

> He **washed** his clothes.

If you insist on your sentence structure, then

> He made his clothes clean *(by washing them)*